# What word would you use to describe a person who is highly judgemental or critical of everything, but also is highly outspoken

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

On searching,I came across "self assertive " and "opinionated" . But neither of them seems to answer the query , fully .

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: ...not to mention better context.

Comment: I would add more specifics as the comments above and rules suggest.  Should those details suggest I might consider using the idiom "high maintenance"  ( although that now has some sexist tinge like 'bossy' does) or "particular" with scare quotes

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of words which come to minds, you can use whichever seems fit -

1. [condemnatory](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condemnatory) - expressing strong disapproval; censorious.
   *"condemnatory statements"*
2. [disparging](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparaging) - expressing the opinion that something is of little worth; derogatory.
   *"disparaging remarks about council houses"*
3. [deprecating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate) - expressing disapproval; disapproving.
   *"he sniffed in a deprecating way"*
4. [scathing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scathing) - witheringly scornful; severely critical.
   *”she launched a scathing attack on the Prime Minister"*
5. [mordant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mordant) - (especially of humour) having or showing a sharp or critical quality; biting.
   *"a mordant sense of humour"*

But all these words, are only suitable for “highly judgmental” and “critical of everything”, and not necessarily for “outspoken”. Therefore I’m listing a few more words for “outspoken” which you can use after the above listed words since they are adjectives.

1. [vociferous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vociferous) - expressing or characterized by vehement opinions; loud and forceful.
   *"he was a vociferous opponent of the takeover"*
2. [candid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candid) - truthful and straightforward; frank.
   *"his responses were remarkably candid"*
3. [forthright](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forthright) (of a person or their manner or speech) direct and outspoken.
   *"his most forthright attack yet on the reforms"*

As an example you could say, “scathingly vociferous” or condemnatorily forthright” and so on, but since your question, asks for a single word, you could just use the any of the five listed words. But for a more detailed description, I’d suggest you to use two.

Comment: This is a good first answer, but we generally link definitions to their sources. Also, you should click in the upper right-hand corner and complete the "Tour" for this site. Doing so will give you a better understanding of what is expected and it will also add 100 points to your reputation. Welcoms to EL&U.

Comment: Hello, Natru. You see the problems ELU throws up. OP asks for a single word fusing the meanings of both your sets of synonyms.

Comment: @MarkHubbard thank you, for your kind words about my answer, and surely I’ll try to link definition to the source, and yes I’ll finish the tour too. Thanks again for the welcome!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes I see your point, but I just wanted to give the OP a wider spectrum of options, so they could choose for themselves, instead of me doing it for them.

Comment: That's not what answers on ELU (or any SE site) are intended to be. A question asking for two answers, one-word synonyms of (a) 'critical of everything' and (b) 'outspoken' would be off-topic as 'not a single question'. A question asking for a single answer, a one-word synonym of say (b) 'outspoken', lacking research, would be close-voted.

Comment: I understand your point. I will surely take care of it in my future answers. I also edited my answer to make it a little more clear that the first five words are enough too, and the rest are simply for more detailed description. I also understand if even that is not right, and considered off topic here. I will surely take care of it next time around, or I could edit out the three words entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple words that may work:

- **[captious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captious)** (adj) marked by an often ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections

  - ex. "captious critics" "a captious complainer"
- **[censorious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/censorious)** (adj) severely critical of others; faultfinding

  - ex. "censorious comments" "a censorious tone"

An example showing how the word would be used in a sentence would be helpful. Without an example sentence, it's hard to say, but I think those cover both a critical nature and outspokenness.